# Table View custom cell button color and title changes on scroll of tableview

Tags: objective-c

I have table view with custom cell with one button which has red color with title verify and on click of it changes to green with title Experience.But the problem is when i scroll buttons which are not clicked are changed to green color With title experience

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";



    BoastsMainCell1 *cell1 =
    (BoastsMainCell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];






    cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if(cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = [[BoastsMainCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }


    [cell1.verifyBnt addTarget:self action:@selector(verifyButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell1;
}



-(void)verifyButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{




    [sender setTitle:@"Experience" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BoastsMainCell1` class you should override `- (void)prepareForReuse`.  What is happening is that the OS is reusing a cell and you should be resetting its properties.  `prepareForReuse` is your opportunity to do that resetting.

[From Apple's documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For
>   performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that
>   are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection
>   state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
>   should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell
>   object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is
>   not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke
>   the superclass implementation.

In your implementation file, BoastsMainCell1.m, you can add a method similar to this:

```
  - (void)prepareForReuse {
        [super prepareForReuse];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
```

Comment: sorry i was implementing it in UIviewcontroller class

Answer (score 0):

you should reset cell state like below:

```
    if(cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = [[BoastsMainCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
//it's just a example. some code like this to reset the UI element.
//    [cell1.verifyBnt setSelected:NO];
//    [cell1 updateCell.....
```

The reason is that the cell will be reused.

Comment: on scroll of table view m getting problem

Comment: @salman4siddiquistackoverflow you didn't get my meaning. After the codes  in my answer, you should add some code to reset the cell. Because the cell will be reused. You should use a data to record the cell states, and when the cell would be reused, change the cell depend on the cell states.

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding that, a TableViewCell will retain the states of its view. But its absolutely wrong. That is, TableViewCell will be reused when you scroll the tableview and reused cells will use default UI states. In your case, you have to keep the 'selected' states of the button, outside of the cell, like a Dictionary in ViewController class. For example, when you get an event from button, store that state in the dictionary. And in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method, you have to check whether the current row has selected state from this dictionary and set the appropriate color values, like,

```
if (dict[@(indexPath.row)] == @(YES)) {
    //Set red color
} else {
   //green color
}
```

Note that, this may not be the perfect way. Only intention is to make you understand how cell will be reused and how you should preserve the cell states..